# How to Create custom woocommerce dashboard Template

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to create custom woocommerce dashboard for my custom wordpress  theme, but i found a error message when i am trying to create custom woocommerce dashboard template.

```
Deprecated: Your theme version of my-account.php template is deprecated since version 2.6! Use the latest version, which supports multiple account pages and navigation, from WC 2.6.0 instead.
```

I have followed the woocommerce template pattern `(yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/my-account.php.)` but nothing help  . Please see the attached image. problem will gone if i edit wp-config.php with `define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );`

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: the error message seems to indicate where things are going wrong unless you are already using the latest version? (version 3.5.0)

Comment: I am using the latest version plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this.
I have to use this two function in `my-account.php` file.
Then the error message gone.

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_account_navigation' ); 
do_action( 'woocommerce_account_content' );
```